# How to choose the SE site to migrate a question to?

Tags: discussion, migration

I wanted to migrate [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29870102/how-to-get-system-load-in-linux) to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) but I was not offered a free-form choice of the sites when clicking though the flag.

I ended up choosing [Super User](https://superuser.com/) as it was the closest match - why is the choice so limited?

Comment: That question isn't of the quality I'd expect for a migration candidate.

Comment: @TZHX: you are correct, but I would prefer to leave the other site's users the liberty to close it if required. In that specific case it is indeed a weak question, though if it was about Chinese I would not know whether it is correct or not.

Comment: @WoJ your preference doesn't feel right, see eg: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: OK, good to know. I also found some quite [hilarious comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl) on Programmers.SE while reading the answer redirected from my question.